# Spring Data Error creating bean with name 'PrRepository' defined in repository.PrRepository defined in : Invocation of init method failed;

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

This is error i am getting atthe time of compilation. I am new at spring and not able to understand the error. Please help me to find out and fix program.

My logs and error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectRepository' defined in repository.ProjectRepository defined in : Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityPathResolver must not be null!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:936)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at domain.Domain.main(Domain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityPathResolver must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.setEntityPathResolver(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.createRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.doCreateRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.createRepositoryFactory(TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 12 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code in Domain.java :

```
   package domain;

   import bl.HibernateUtil;
   import entity.Address;
   import entity.Employee;
   import entity.Project;
   import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
   import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
   import repository.AddressRepository;
   import repository.EmployeeRepository;
   import repository.ProjectRepository;
   import service.AddressService;
   import service.EmployeeService;
   import service.ProjectService;

   import java.sql.Date;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.util.*;
   
   public class Domain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        AddressRepository addressRepository = context.getBean(AddressRepository.class);

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setCountry("DC");
        address.setCity("Gotham city");
        address.setStreet("Arkham street 1");
        address.setPostCode("12345");

        Project project = new Project();
        project.setTitle("Gotham PD");

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstName("James");
        employee.setLastName("Gordon");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(1939, Calendar.MAY, 1);

        employee.setBirthday(new Date(calendar.getTime().getTime()));
        employee.setAddress(address);

        Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        employees.add(employee);
        project.setEmployees(employees);

        Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        projects.add(project);
        employee.setProjects(projects);

        //addressRepository.save(address);

        System.out.println("***********");

      //  System.out.println(employeeRepository.findByFirstNameAndLastName("James","Gordon"));
    }

   }
```

My pom file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.vserdiuk.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-xml-mapping</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.214</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</project>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

my Entity class:

```
 package entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity @Table(name = "ADDRESS") public class Address {

@Id
// @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;

@Column(name = "COUNTRY")
private String country;

@Column(name = "CITY")
private String city;

@Column(name = "STREET")
private String street;

@Column(name = "POST_CODE", length = 10)
private String postCode;

public Address() {

}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getPostCode() {
    return postCode;
}

public void setPostCode(String postCode) {
    this.postCode = postCode;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Address{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", country='" + country + '\'' +
            ", city='" + city + '\'' +
            ", street='" + street + '\'' +
            ", postCode='" + postCode + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

My Repository Class:

```
package repository;
import entity.Address; 
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address,Long> { }
```

Result: I want to get info from h2 database with spring data. And i want to write some info into database.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you checked the answers on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459543/error-when-creating-jpa-repository-entitypathresolver-must-not-be-null

Comment: why your id property is commented ? the error means that your repository cannot find your entity